# Selenium 4.X : EventFiringDecorator throws error when using JavascriptExecutor to click webelement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
public class DummyClass {

    WebDriver driver;
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void testNewFeature() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        WebDriverListener customListener = new DriverEventListener();
        driver = new EventFiringDecorator(customListener).decorate(new ChromeDriver());
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Sign in']"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);

    }
}

public class DriverEventListener implements WebDriverListener {

    public void beforeExecuteScript(WebDriver driver, String script, Object[] args) {
        System.out.println("beforeExecuteScript ");
    }

    public void afterExecuteScript(WebDriver driver, String script, Object[] args, Object result) {
        System.out.println("afterExecuteScript ");
    }
    }
```

**Throws error as**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal type:
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15    at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.WebElementToJsonConverter.apply(WebElementToJsonConverter.java:85)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> at
> java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:550)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.decorators.WebDriverDecorator.call(WebDriverDecorator.java:228)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.decorators.DefaultDecorated.call(DefaultDecorated.java:48)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.support.decorators.WebDriverDecorator.lambda$createProxy$0(WebDriverDecorator.java:287)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.executeScript(Unknown Source)

Comment: that is still in alpha testing.. Selenium latest stable version is `3.141.59` V3. If you think that could be an issue feel free to raise a ticket here `https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues`

Comment: Yes i did that thank you, also i found prior build alternative with EventFiringWebDriver

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it is stated that it will be fixed with the next version. Ticket - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9483

I encountered this issue with selenium 4.0.0-beta-3